# Why does the body effect result in these \$V_{OH}\$ and \$V_{OL}\$ values?

Tags: vlsi

Consider the following circuit and discussion which come from my textbook (Brown and Varnesic *Fundamentals of Digital Logic*):

[image]

Of course, the exercise is to notice that NMOS and PMOS are very bad in a PUN and PDN, respectively. However, I can't understand how they are arguing from the specific values of the output voltages \$V_{OH}\$ and \$V_{OL}\$. It seems they are assuming (for simplicity given that this is not a devices textbok) that if the source and body of a MOSFET are not connected then the threshold voltage is \$1.5V_T\$. *Given this assumption*, how do they arrive at 3.5 V and 1.5 V?

Note that \$V_{DD} = 5 V\$ in this system. For example, in the case of a 11 input where we assume \$V_f = 0\$ initially, we can imagine the PUN pulling \$V_f\$ up. Clearly transistor MN1 is shut off once we arrive at \$V_f = 3.5 V\$ (its overdrive voltage is then 0). However, I can't see why we wouldn't have shut off earlier in this case given that MN2 (with its source at an intermediate node which is higher than that of the source of MN1, \$V_f\$) has the same gate voltage of 5 V applied to it?